# call an api GET method in dapp - blocked by CORS policy

Tags: web3js, dapp-development

I am trying to create a dapp(web3js - truffle) where an API - GET method has to be implemented by setting 'x-api-key' on header.(OS - Linux) Here is the code :

app.js

```
//1st method
var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;

var data = null;

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.withCredentials = true;

xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {
if (this.readyState === 4) {
console.log(this.responseText);
}
});
xhr.open("GET", api);
xhr.setRequestHeader("x-api-key", key);
xhr.setRequestHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
xhr.send(data);


//2nd method

$.ajax({

      url: "api",
      type: "GET",
      beforeSend: function (xhr) {
         xhr.setRequestHeader('x-api-key', key);
      },
      success: function (resp) {
          console.log("Result :"+JSON.stringify(resp))
      },
      error: function(result){
        console.log("Error : "+JSON.stringify(result));
      }
  });
```

On chrome I get

> Blocked by CORS policy: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'

I am able to get data using POSTMAN and on an executable js script. Tried by adding `Allow-Control-Allow-Origin: *` extension and enabling it on chrome. Then output was :

> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It
>   does not have HTTP ok status

By trying above piece of code on meanstack - server side, it works. Do I have to write Nodejs backend for dapp? Is there other method to resolve it?

Comment: youwan you are trying to access the app from the browser and the CORS  policy is blocking your request? if that is the case just disable cors policy in the browser. This happens when you are calling the app locally.

Comment: Thanks Jaime, but we can't expect each users to disable cors policy in the browser...

Comment: indeed, but that will not happen to the users, is happening to you because your web server is in the localhost. Try to access it from outside your local network and most likely it will work without disabling CORS

Comment: I tried adding code for API call on main Controller(MEAN STACK) and uploaded in heroku to test it, still same issue.